# Mysql Database connection vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to connect to a database but it doesn't work...

Code:

```
        Dim conn As MysqlConnection

    conn = New Mysqlconnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=http://www.*****.net/phpMyAdmin; user id=*****; password=****; database=login"

    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error connecting to database!")
    End Try
```

it alsways says Error connecting to database!

what's the problem??

Comment: `Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MsgBox(myerror.message)
    End Try`
This will give you more detailed exception information.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `http://www.*****.net/phpMyAdmin` for your server name. it should be just your domain name(hostname) `mydomain.com` or IP address `192.168.0.10`

it should look as follow:

```
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
conn.ConnectionString = "Host=192.168.0.10;user=root;password=root"
conn.Open()
```

Comment: Even if i do this         'conn.ConnectionString = "Host=***.*.**.***; user id=*******; password=******"' it doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that MySQL Connector/NET is installed. Check all credentials are correct. Then try this snippet.

```
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class MySQLConnect
    Private db_con As New MySqlConnection
    Private Sub connect()
        Dim dbname As String = "DBNAME"
        Dim dbhost As String = "localhost"
        Dim user As String = "root"
        Dim pass As String = "DBPASSWORD"


        If Not db_con Is Nothing Then db_con.Close()
        db_con.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", dbhost, user, pass, dbname)

        Try
            db_con.Open()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Database Error:[" & ex.Message & "]")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Try [this link](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-2), it's very straight forward.

Answer (score -2):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class LoginForm1
    Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection

    Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        mysqlconnection = New MySqlConnection
        mysqlconnection.ConnectionString = "server=servername.com;port=portnum;user id=username ;pwd=password;database=databasename"
        'mysqlconnection.Open()
        Try
            mysqlconnection.Open()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error connecting to database!")
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        MsgBox("connected to database!")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have some formatting problems with your code. It's also usually desirable to add a little bit of text explaining your solution. You can edit your post to make these changes.